# Rename specific files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am trying to do a program that renames the files that are not named in order for example :

**input:** in a folder we have these files : `['spam001.txt', 'spam002.txt', 'spam003.txt', 'spam005.txt', 'spam007.txt']`

**output:** i want to end up with the same files named like this : `['spam001.txt', 'spam002.txt', 'spam003.txt', 'spam004.txt', 'spam005.txt']`

Here is what i have done until now :

```
import os,shutil

count = 1 
path = '.\\filling in the gaps' #this is the folder where i have the .txt files
files = os.listdir(path)
for i in files:
    if(i[6] != str(count)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,i),'spam00%s.txt' %(count))
    count = count+1
```

My problem is that when I run the program, for the output mentioned above , I get `['spam001.txt', 'spam002.txt', 'spam003.txt']` in the 'filling in the gaps' folder and I get
`['spam004.txt', 'spam005.txt']` in the folder that contains 'filling in the gaps' folder.

Basically, my program renames the files, but the files end up in another folder. Any idea why this is happening?
This is where the files go:

[image]

Comment: Because the second parameter (dest) of the `rename` function also uses `path`. Therefore the renamed file is output into the directory defined by `path`.

Comment: Do you mean every time a new folder is created inside the filling the gap folder?

Comment: I tried with the edited code above and the same thing happens.

Comment: I also added a picture with the location of the .txt files after i ran the program

Comment: Basically you need the **full path** to the file being renamed, and the **full path** to where the renamed file will be stored.  These two paths slot into the `rename` function as `source`, `dest`.  At the minute, the files are being output to the script’s directory as a path is not being specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code, providing your desired results:

```
import os

count = 1
path = '.\\filling in the gaps'  # this is the folder where i have the .txt files
files = os.listdir(path)
for i in files:
    if (i[6] != str(count)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, i),
                  os.path.join(path, 'spam00%s.txt' % (count))
                  )
    count = count + 1
```